# Which view function load after pop-up exit in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a login screen which is saying "SingnIn" when user is clicking on that he getting a pop of facebook login screen.

I want that if somebody successfully logged in, I want to change SignIn text with their name. But I am not getting place where I should write that part of code. Which view function load again after pop screen exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implemented facebook connect and if you meant facebook login then after login you can write code in facebook delegate method.

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {

    //Write code here for changing label for user name
}
```